in BLE mesh do i only need one provisionor or each node should be a provisionor if i have a big number of nodes?
I'm working on an ESP-BLE-Mesh project and I want to know , if I have a big number of nodes do I only need one "Provisionor" and it'll provision the rest o the nodes or each node should have a provisioning model ?
I tried with only two nodes and one "Provisioner" but I didn't try with many nodes and one Provisionor .

An unprovisioned Bluetooth mesh device may send Bluetooth LE advertisement packets, which announce
that it supports the GATT provisioning service. The GATT provisioning service allows a Bluetooth LE device with provisioning capabilities
to establish a connection to the unprovisioned device and start the provisioning process.
Alternatively, the unprovisioned mesh device can start sending unprovisioned mesh beacons allowing another Bluetooth mesh node with
provisioning capabilities to provision it over the mesh bearer.
